# from single jpg to web conversion to all files in dir

Tags: python, image-size

i made python code to convert jpg into webp

```
from PIL import Image
import PIL
import os
import glob



# Open The Image:
image_path = "D:/..../image_name.jpg"

image = Image.open(image_path)


# Convert the image to RGB Colour:
image = image.convert('RGB')

# Save The Image as webp:
new_image_path = "D:/.../converted_image_name.webp"

image.save(new_image_path, 'webp')

#open converted image for inspection

new_image = Image.open(new_image_path)
new_image.show()
```

Don't know how to build a function that does the conversion for all files in folder, keeping the orginial file_names.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution to your problem:

```
from pathlib import Path

from PIL import Image
import PIL
import os
import glob

# the path to the directory containing the images
directory_path = 'D:\PATH'

def convert_images(directory_path):
    for image_path in os.listdir(directory_path):
        if image_path.endswith(".jpg"):
            image = Image.open(os.path.join(directory_path, image_path))
            # get image filename without an extension
            name = Path(image_path).stem
            rgb_image = image.convert('RGB')
            new_image_path = f"{name}.webp"
            rgb_image.save(os.path.join(directory_path, new_image_path), 'webp')
            new_image = Image.open(new_image_path)
            new_image.show()
            continue
        else:
            continue


convert_images(directory_path)
```

Comment: I get this error

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'resized_marie_jo-lingerie-underwired_bra-avero-0100410-%28maincolor%29-0_3515169.jpg'  so it can find the file name, but doesn't open it

Comment: That's weird. did you set the `directory_path = 'D:\PATH'` variable to the directory containing the images(not the actual image path)? Plus, is error line number shown? It can help me understand where there is an issue.

Comment: errorline ----> 7             image = Image.open(image_path).  directory_path = 'D:/Lokale schijf/VANDERLINDEN/datafiles/BRANDS/VDV/images/SS2023/Python_API_imports/'

Comment: Can you replace line 7 with the folowing `image = Image.open(os.path.join(directory_path, image_path))`. Let me know if that works

Comment: I added the join of dir_path and image_path also in the line where the new .webp_file is saved: rgb_image.save(os.path.join(directory_path, new_image_path), 'webp')  and now it works fine. I've made an answer with the final code.

Answer (score 0):

final code

```
from pathlib import Path

from PIL import Image
import PIL
import os
import glob

# the path to the directory containing the images
directory_path =  'D:/Lokale schijf/SS2023/Python_API_imports/'


def convert_images(directory_path):
    for image_path in os.listdir(directory_path):
        if image_path.endswith(".jpg"):
            image = Image.open(os.path.join(directory_path, image_path)) 
            # get image filename without an extension
            name = Path(image_path).stem
            rgb_image = image.convert('RGB')
            new_image_path = f"{name}.webp"
            rgb_image.save(os.path.join(directory_path, new_image_path), 'webp') 
            new_image = Image.open(new_image_path)
            new_image.show()
            continue
        

convert_images(directory_path)
```